# Can a hero start a dungeon with a bonus?

Tags: guild-of-dungeoneering

In the game 'Guild of Dungeoneering', beside the advantage of the level he gained, is there a guild expansion or anything that can give a bonus to the battles?

[image]

Comment: I keep losing, and need an advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click [Expand Guild]:

- Build a Talisman/Idol/Shrine will give your hero a starting bonuses
- Building a Loot item will add improved gear options that are made available to your hero after winning a battle (e.g. if you beat a level 2 monster you get a level 2 item)
- Other character classes (Cat Burglar, Bruiser, etc) have significantly better starting decks than the Chump does.  Strangely the Chump and the Mime are the only two 1st tier characters that can't die to the Rubber Ducky.
- Passing certain checkpoints in the story will grant bonus health to all of your dungeoneers.